# Entity Framework 6.1 Code First MySql entity tracking persists across context

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm having an odd problem with a DbContext saving duplicate objects. I have a graph of objects similar to the following:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}
public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime OrderDate {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Product> Products {get;set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Orders> Orders {get;set;}
}

public class MyContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Order> Orders {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

This is a contrived example of course, but if I want to save two new Customers. I add them with DbContext.Customers.Add(). The customer is completely filled out with orders and products. It saves all that data just fine. But if a second customer is added, even with a totally new DbContext instance, it will add the original customer a second time. I still have a reference to the original customer, but I did not add it to the new context instance. Yet DbContext.SaveChanges will save two customers, the original one a second time, and the new one. This will exponentially increase the number of records I'm saving. And this applies to the entire graph. Orders and Products are also duplicated.

If I manually detach the object after saving, it won't save duplicates. Since I'm adding an entire Customer at once, I have to loop through all child entities and detach those as well. If I only detach Customer, it will still duplicate previous Orders and Products. This even seems to happen if I turn off Change Tracking!

Any ideas?

Comment: Ef doesn't work like that. Never had that kind of problem. Please, show the code that has that problem, so that we can reproduce it, and give you a solution. Please. see this: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve If you don't add that code, we cannot reproduce the problem, and this question shpuld be closed.

Comment: Do you call saveChanges in two separated instances of the DbContext ? do you dispose the context after you called the first SaveChanges ? make sure that you do that and you don''t use a singleton dbcontext.

Comment: I was using separate instances of DbContext in using blocks, yes. I at least figured out what was happening, but someone will have to explain to me why this happens if it isn't a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I tried, as suggested, to duplicate this in a small application to make it easier to share. But I couldn't get it to happen. I went over my code for the 20th time and finally noticed something.

Let's say I added a new class Company at the top of the hierarchy. So each Company had many Customers. If I add a company, save it, but keep the reference, and then use that reference to assign to the navigation property of each of the "Customers" before I add them, it will save duplicates. Even if every save (Company, Customer 1, Customer 2, etc.) has a completely new DbContext in a using statement.

I guess for now the moral of this story is don't assign navigation properties in this instance. Instead add Id columns and use Id values.

[Here's my example](http://pastebin.com/k9LvyWdE) that reproduces the issue I'm talking about. Maybe this is something you "just don't do" but i was not aware that it would result in duplicates.